# In a winforms tabcontrol, is there a way to make a certain tab visible but not selectable?

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol

In a winforms tabcontrol, is there a way to make a certain tab visible but not selectable?
I can make it Visible = false, but I would like the tab to show up but simply not be clickable/selectable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the Selecting event and set Cancel=true when it is that special Tab.